# Why is my interface not found?

Tags: php, require

I'm learning PHP OOP and right now I built a basic calculator.

Here is my code at `index.php`:

```
require_once 'Calculator.class.php';
require_once 'Adder.class.php';
require_once 'Substract.class.php';
require_once 'Operator.interface.php';
require_once 'Multiplier.class.php';
require_once 'Devider.class.php';

$c = new Calculator;

$c->setOperation(new Adder);
$c->calculate(10,50); // 60

echo $c->getResult();
```

And this is the `Calculator` class file:

```
class Calculator
{
    protected $result;
    protected $operation;
    public function setOperation(OperatorInterface $operation)
    {
        $this->operation = $operation;
        // var_dump($operation);        
    }
    public function calculate()
    {
        foreach(func_get_args() as $number)
        {
            $this->result = $this->operation->run($number,$this->result);
        }
    }
    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

And this is the interface that is being called within this class file:

```
interface OperatorInterface
{
    public function run($number,$result);
}
```

And this is the class `Adder` which is called from the `index.php`:

```
class Adder implements OperatorInterface
{
    public function run($number,$result)
    {
        return $result + $number;
    }
}
```

As you can see it looks nice and okay... however I get this weird error:

> Fatal error: Interface 'OperatorInterface' not found on line 2 Adder.php

So line 2 of `Adder` Class is this:

```
class Adder implements OperatorInterface
```

Which means I have not include the interface properly. But I did include that.

So why am I getting this error?

Where did I make my mistake?

Comment: Consider using an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: [No repro](https://repl.it/repls/KnowingReasonableConferences) - It is most likely something to do with the way you are including your classes.

Comment: Even better - using [composer autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the `Operator.interface.php` file before the `Adder.class.php` file, otherwise when the compiler gets to the `Adder` class, it hasn't yet encountered anything called `OperatorInterface`, so it doesn't recognise it and can't verify that it's valid to declare that the Adder class implements it. Since it's also referenced in the `Calculator` class, you should include it before that as well.

```
require_once 'Operator.interface.php';
require_once 'Calculator.class.php';
require_once 'Adder.class.php';
require_once 'Substract.class.php';
require_once 'Multiplier.class.php';
require_once 'Devider.class.php';
```

It should be that simple - for future reference you should always order your includes so that dependencies between them can be satisfied, because they get processed in the order you supply them.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tested that but nothing changed!

Comment: @pikiowaefrae I just changed it to move the Operator interface right to the top above the Calculator as well, try that. If that doesn't work, well....are you sure that OperatorInterface code is in the correct file??? As you can see, if all the code is correctly included, in that order, then it works nicely: https://eval.in/998718